# How to create Link Loadpage on header, without load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How do I create a link with loading above, without reloading the refresh section (in the browser).
And what is the name of the technique?
Example : https://phpsound.com/demo/track/17/im-waiting-for-you

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking that "Load More" section it is AJAX when page scroll down then call AJAX

Comment: Not that bro, but the link when in the click like (the example that thread I created)

Comment: Then it is modal it is hided and when you clikc like then show